# Lease ends May 28, 2018; but, moving out today (4/29)

Tags: united-states, rent, wisconsin

My lease ends on May 28, 2018 and I’m moving in with my uncle today (4/29) because it’s more cost efficient. I will still be paying the rent for the month of May as it’s the last month in my lease and I’d rather not have any issues with ending my lease early and I was just wondering if this is okay. A while back there was a leak in my bathroom ceiling and they came by to check it out. Since there’s going to be a new tenant for the month of June, I’m not sure if they’re going to come in and check it during May. I don’t want them to come in and see the place empty and think I abandoned it or something. Should I tell them? Or am I okay to move since my lease ends that month anyways?

Comment: Speaking of leaks, what do you think happens if a pipe breaks between when you leave and when your lease expires, and you aren't there to turn off the water and report it in a reasonable period of time?

Comment: If you're paying all of the rent due, why would there be  "any issues with ending my lease early" ? The landlord might be very happy if the next tenant was willing to move in sooner, possibly collecting two monthly rent checks in the last month.  Pay the rent, turn in your keys, and close this chapter of your life.

Comment: @BobBaerker I'm pretty sure the lease goes both ways, and the landlord cannot overlap two leases. It also doesn't address my point that by leaving early, the OP is forcing the landlord to find an alternate means of keeping an eye on the property a month earlier than expected.

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that the landlord can overlap two leases.  If the tenant pays the last month in advance, moves out, and both parties agree (and sign) a termination agreement, the property is now free to rent again albeit one month sooner.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, this would necessitate a refund to the tenant that moved out early, not sure if that's the norm. All the more reason to let them know, though, imo.

Comment: Does your landlord know already that you are not planning on extending your lease?

Comment: Hi, yes, my landlord already knows. I believe someone has already signed a lease for my place after I move out. I live in Wisconsin, USA if that matters any. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: @chepner: The same thing that happens if someone has to travel for work in the middle of a lease, and isn't there to turn off the water and report the leak: it's the landlord's plumbing that failed, and the landlord's problem to fix.  Only potential liability would be allowing interior temperature to drop below freezing during a time of year when freezing temperatures are reasonably possible.

Answer (score 9):

I would tell them so that you can have your final walk-through and be done with it, surrender keys, etc. Then you don't have to think about it again. Your lease may have language specific to moving out early, but typically that's focused on notifying that you don't intend to renew. I've never seen language in a lease that would punish someone for paying rent but moving out a little early.

In some jurisdictions, the landlord is required to take reasonable steps to find a replacement when a tenant moves out early (they can't just collect rent on an empty unit for months on end without re-listing it) to mitigate cost to the former tenant. Given that it's just a month I wouldn't bank on recovering any rent, but if they find someone to move in prior to May 28 you'd be owed a refund (this may vary by jurisdiction as well).

So, there's likely no downside to letting them know you've moved already (check your lease), and the upside is that you don't have to think about the place anymore and there's an outside chance you'd get some of May's rent back.